# How to prevent spam comments and registrations in Telligent Community Server?

Tags: spam-prevention, community-server

I've added captcha from [codebetter site](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2007/04/27/captcha-for-community-server-2007.aspx) on blog posts and registration form.

Number of spam comments was decreased but 1-2 per day is a rule.

Do you know how to prevent spam comments and registrations? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Honeypots](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html) work well.  Here's a [testimonial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536457/whats-the-best-practice-way-to-process-a-contact-form/1539933#1539933).

Answer (score 1):

Telligent Community comes with a number of pre-defined spam rules. You have to enable them in the Control Panel. You can find them under Site Administration. The exact location will vary depending upon the version of Telligent Community being used. You can tweak the sensitivity of the rules. With them enabled and tweaked appropriately, you'll be able to catch all the comment spam. Registration spam is another. Captcha is the best thing we've found to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a new CAPTCHA for Telligent Community 6.0 and put it on the Telligent Marketplace here:

http://telligent.com/marketplace/m/marketplace/1353178.aspx